# Reflectively filter the new parameters in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I want to filter the explicitly defined query parameters from the Map of all parameters in a Spring controller, so that the resultant Map should only contain any undefined/new parameters.

Example:

Sample Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/foos")
public String updateFoos(@RequestParam String param1,
                         @RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams) {
    // do something
}
```

Sample URL:

```
https://localhost:8080/api/foos?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Current result: "**allParams**" Map contains two entries:

```
param1=value1
param2=value2
```

Expected result: "**allParams**" Map should only contain one entry:

```
param2=value2
```

Is there a way or is it even possible using Spring reflections or something similar to filter out the " **allParams**" Map such that it only contains the entries for new parameters? Without manually removing every predefined parameters one by one?

Comment: You would need to write your own `MethodArgumentHandler` for this and invent your own annotation. What is the use-case you are trying to solve here? Why do you need a map containing the parameters that aren't part of the signature? Why is it impossible to use the map with the parameters?

Comment: Use-case: The controller is a part of legacy code, client wants to send new parameters and trigger a new logic based on these new parameters. Since it is legacy code, we don't want to change the controller signature way too much as we don't know the impact on usage, hence adding the "allParams" Map and looking for a way to just have the new parameters passed from the URL in this Map.

It is not impossible, we can use the Map since it contains all the parameters, but I was looking for a better/cleaner way to pass around only the needed parameters.

Comment: As stated you would need to invent your own annotation. The easiest is to just change the method and add the parameters (or even better bind to a class and check which ones are there) as optional, check if they are they are there. The easiest is to just introduce a DTO which holds all parameters and in the method check which ones are available and depending on that do your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't mix.
You can use @RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams

and get specific param from map in method body.